# Readiness Check - PHP Settings Check Error

Tags: magento2

I am trying to enable a module through the backend (after failed attempts from Putty). But im getting and error. im sharing the image below

[image]

I am not able to find a php ini file in my root directory but i say user.ini and .htaccess and both of them contain memory_limit = 756M

i tried to run the command shown in the image. the result i have is

carefdgi@md-in-63 [~/public_html]# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/alt/php70/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/alt/php70/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/alt/php70/link/conf
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/alt/php70/link/conf/alt_php.ini

not able to find such a folder.

Comment: create php.ini in root and set value on root

Comment: There should be php.ini.sample file. Rename it to php.ini or copy this file, paste it and rename the copied one to php.ini file.

Comment: i copied all the content from php.ini sample, created new php.ini, pasted all the data and changed the memory limit to 756M. Still the issue persists.

Comment: @Tanish If you can't access any files in `/opt/alt/php70/etc/` then the user you are logged into the server as likely doesn't have permissions to see or edit it. Therefore, contact your hosting provider and ask them to change it.

Comment: @Tanish, have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora how i do restart the server?

Comment: If you have access to the SSH with root previllage, then
        for Ubuntu: **`sudo service apache2 restart`**
        for centOS: **`sudo service httpd restart`**

Comment: as i have a shared host, not able to get root access